# jpg url redirection htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After looking around, I didn't find a solution to that… I have a website in html only on a vhost, i put an htaccess on it. Here is the point :

Portfolio here : wwwmydomainfr/Photographies.html

The photos open in a lightbox, i can share these photos with a share button
ex : wwwmydomainfr/Photos/image1.jpg

What i'm looking for is to redirect the people to 
wwwwmydomainfr/Photographies.html 
when they hit 
wwwmydomainfr/Photos/image1.jpg

but the thing is that I cannot access the photo if i use a redirection... "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later"

For now :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ wwwmydomainfr/Photographies.html [L]
```

I tried to add but without success :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?wwwmydomainfr/Photographies.html [nc]
```

Any ideas ?

UPDATE

And also, when I arrive to the url of the image at first, it doesn’t work, only when I load again the url, any ideas ? It looks like it's kind of random the redirection... Sometime the images are not available too.. Maybe I can add something in the directory of the images ?

The code at the end :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mywebsite.fr/Photographies.html [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ http://www.mywebsite.fr/Photographies.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right to try and use the HTTP_REFERER conditional because otherwise the jpeg image resolves to an html file. Without this conditional a request to wwwmydomainfr/Photos/image1.jpg, is redirected to wwwwmydomainfr/Photographies.html, which I assume has the image embedded with the `<img ref='wwwmydomainfr/Photos/image1.jpg'>` tag, the when the browser tries to retrieve the image its redirected to the html and not to the source of a jpeg.

Only thing I can spot in your rewrite condition which is not correct is the unescaped dot and the inclusion of the www in front of the domain. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(jpg)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomainfr
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ wwwmydomainfr/Photographies.html [L]/Photographies.html [nc]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact, it was already working (just find out) but I took yours for the www and didn't get the "unescaped dot"  ?

Comment: In the rewrite condition which is matching HTTP_REFERER, you have a full stop in the group `(www.)`. I think this needs to be escaped `(www\.)` otherwise it will match any character rather than just a dot.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to not work on fixefox and 1 of 2 times on safari, i don't know what to do, maybe changing all the strategy...